# I want to clone a git rep. into my neovim config but it gives me a fatal

Tags: terminal, neovim

I want to run the following command:
`git clone https://github.com/ChristianChiarulli/nvim.git ~/.config/nvim`

Which gives me `fatal: destination path '/Users/Me/.config/nvim' already exists and is not an empty directory`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command aims to replace your `~/.config/nvim` completely. So either delete your nvim config directory, or clone into another dir e.g. `~/.config/nvim/` and it will be cloned into `~/.config/nvim/nvim`.

Comment: thanks again! I really have to read myself into this stuff!

Comment: Happy to solve your problem! We all have to start somewhere :)